# Query() with LoadAsync() does not return an entity although it should

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

```
context.Pupils.Attach(pupil);
```

*The pupil.SchoolclassCodes collection is empty but there must be a schoolclassCode because in the bottom LoadAsync method is the SchoolclassCode with the Id I query here*

```
await context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Query().Where(s => s.Id == schoolclassCodeId).LoadAsync();
```

*Fill the pupil with ONE schoolclassCode in the pupil.SchoolclassCodes collection*

```
await context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).LoadAsync();
```

Why does the **bottom LoadAsync** work but not the **top LoadAsync**?

**UPDATE**

Sorry for the confusion about the pupil.SchoolclassCodeId which is a [NotMappedAttribute]

This is the relationship.

Pupil N has M SchoolclassCodes.

Each entity has a collection of the other entity.

The last LoadAsync works as I said, there is no problem in the relationship setup.

The problem is the first LoadAsync does NOT worka as described above!

LAZY Loading is completely disabled! I use no virtual props anywhere!

**UPDATE 2**

```
public class SchoolclassCode
{
    public SchoolclassCode()
    {
        Pupils = new HashSet<Pupil>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ISet<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }

}

public class Pupil
{
    public Pupil()
    {
        SchoolclassCodes = new HashSet<SchoolclassCode>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ISet<SchoolclassCode> SchoolclassCodes { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int SchoolclassCodeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It seems that a `Pupil` has a collection of `SchoolclassCode`, i.e. `Pupil` and `SchoolclassCode` are one-many, yet a `Pupil` has a `SchoolclassCodeId`, suggesting `Pupil` and `SchoolclassCode` are many-one or one-zero..one. Could you show us the relationship between your entities?

Comment: I updated my question with more info!

Comment: Can you please add the definition of your entities?

Comment: how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: @jj because I debugged both scenarios!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field `Pupil.SchoolclassCodeId` is apparently unused for the purpose of this question, so let's forget it.

Your second query:

```
await context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).LoadAsync();
```

works as expected. We can verify it with the following code:

```
await context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).LoadAsync();
Console.WriteLine("IsLoaded = " + context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).IsLoaded);
foreach (var code in pupil.SchoolclassCodes)
  Console.WriteLine("  " + code.Id);
```

Suppose the `pupil` has three elements in its `SchoolclassCodes`, then `IsLoaded` will be `true`, and the `foreach` loop will show three ids.

Then comes your first query:

```
await context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Query().Where(s => s.Id == schoolclassCodeId).LoadAsync();
```

and let's test it:

```
var pupil = context.Pupils.First();
var schoolclassCodeId = 1;
await context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Query().Where(s => s.Id == schoolclassCodeId).LoadAsync();
Console.WriteLine("IsLoaded = " + context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).IsLoaded);
foreach (var code in pupil.SchoolclassCodes)
  Console.WriteLine("  " + code.Id);
```

Suppose there indeed is a `SchoolclassCode` which `Id` is `1`, the `AsyncLoad` should load exactly one `SchoolclassCode` into memory. Yet in the output you can see `IsLoaded = false`, and the `foreach` gives nothing at all! Why?

Well, first the `AsyncLoad` is not applied to `Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes)`, but an `IQueryable` derived from it, so `IsLoaded` should be `false`, this is understandable.

But one `SchoolclassCode` is indeed loaded into the context:

```
foreach (var code in context.SchoolclassCodes.Local)
  Console.WriteLine("  " + code.Id);
```

this `foreach` outputs a single `1`. So why we can't find that `SchoolclassCode` in `pupil.SchoolclassCodes`?

The answer is: the relationship between `SchoolclassCode` and `Pupil` is many-to-many. In such circumstances Entity Framework does NOT do relationship fixup, i.e. automatically adding a `SchoolclassCode` to `Pupil.SchoolclassCodes`, so you'll not see it there. If you really want to fix up the relationship, you'll have to do it manually.

## Update 1

Quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx):

> The `Query` method provides access to the underlying query that the Entity Framework will use when loading related entities. You can then use LINQ to apply filters to the query before executing it with a call to a LINQ extension method such as `ToList`, `Load`, etc. The `Query` method can be used with both reference and collection navigation properties but is most useful for collections where it can be used to load only part of the collection.

It is a little confusing. It seems to be contradicting to my argument, but it's not. Actually, in the above quote the word "load" means "load into the context", not "load into the navigation property", so both MSDN and my answer are correct. To prove my claim, let's begin with a few experiments, then we'll dive into the source code.

#### The Model

For demonstration purposes, we add another class into the model:

```
public class Pupil
{
  public Pupil()
  {
    Book = new HashSet<Book>();
    SchoolclassCodes = new HashSet<SchoolclassCode>();
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ISet<Book> Books { get; set; }
  public ISet<SchoolclassCode> SchoolclassCodes { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Pupil Pupil { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolclassCode
{
  public SchoolclassCode()
  {
    Pupils = new HashSet<Pupil>();
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ISet<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship between `Pupil` and `SchoolclassCode` is many-to-many, as before, and the relationship between `Pupil` and the newly added `Book` is one-to-many. The context class is:

```
public class SchoolEntities: DbContext
{
  public SchoolEntities()
    : base("name=SchoolEntities")
  {
  }

  public DbSet<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
  public DbSet<SchoolclassCode> SchoolclassCodes { get; set; }
}
```

#### The Data

We have the following entries in the database:

```
Pupil  (Id = 1)
  the Books property contains:
    Book  (Id = 1)
    Book  (Id = 2)
  the SchoolclassCodes property contains:
    SchoolclassCode  (Id = 1)
    SchoolclassCode  (Id = 2)
    SchoolclassCode  (Id = 3)
```

#### Experiment 1: Direct Load

We load related data directly into the navigation property. For simplicity, we use the `Load` method instead of `LoadAsync`. They do exactly the same, except that the former is synchronous and the latter is asynchronous. The code:

```
using (var context = new SchoolEntities()) {
  Console.WriteLine("Books direct load");
  var pupil = context.Pupils.First();
  context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.Books).Load();
  Console.WriteLine("  IsLoaded = " + context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.Books).IsLoaded);
  Console.WriteLine("  Items in the pupil:");
  foreach (var item in pupil.Books)
    Console.WriteLine("    " + item.Id);
  Console.WriteLine("  Items in the context:");
  foreach (var item in context.Books.Local)
    Console.WriteLine("    " + item.Id);
}
using (var context = new SchoolEntities()) {
  Console.WriteLine("SchoolclassCodes direct load");
  var pupil = context.Pupils.First();
  context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Load();
  Console.WriteLine("  IsLoaded = " + context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).IsLoaded);
  Console.WriteLine("  Items in the pupil:");
  foreach (var item in pupil.SchoolclassCodes)
    Console.WriteLine("    " + item.Id);
  Console.WriteLine("  Items in the context:");
  foreach (var item in context.SchoolclassCodes.Local)
    Console.WriteLine("    " + item.Id);
}
```

and the output:

```
Books direct load
  IsLoaded = True
  Items in the pupil:
    1
    2
  Items in the context:
    1
    2
SchoolclassCodes direct load
  IsLoaded = True
  Items in the pupil:
    1
    2
    3
  Items in the context:
    1
    2
    3
```

The experiment is divided into two parts, one for `Books` and one for `SchoolclassCodes`. Two contexts are used to make sure the two parts do not interfere with each other. We use the collection's `Load` method to load related data directly into the navigation property. The results show that:

1. the collection's `IsLoaded` property is set to `true`;
2. the loaded data can be found in the navigation properties (i.e. `pupil.Books` and `pupil.SchoolclassCodes`);
3. the loaded data can also be found in the context (i.e. `context.Books.Local` and `context.SchoolclassCodes.Local`).

#### Experiment 2: Partial Load with Query

We load part of the related data using the `Query` method followed by a `Where`:

```
using (var context = new SchoolEntities()) {
  Console.WriteLine("Books partial query load");
  var pupil = context.Pupils.First();
  context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.Books).Query().Where(s => s.Id == 1).Load();
  Console.WriteLine("  IsLoaded = " + context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.Books).IsLoaded);
  Console.WriteLine("  Items in the pupil:");
  foreach (var item in pupil.Books)
    Console.WriteLine("    " + item.Id);
  Console.WriteLine("  Items in the context:");
  foreach (var item in context.Books.Local)
    Console.WriteLine("    " + item.Id);
}
using (var context = new SchoolEntities()) {
  Console.WriteLine("SchoolclassCodes partial query load");
  var pupil = context.Pupils.First();
  context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Query().Where(s => s.Id == 1).Load();
  Console.WriteLine("  IsLoaded = " + context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).IsLoaded);
  Console.WriteLine("  Items in the pupil:");
  foreach (var item in pupil.SchoolclassCodes)
    Console.WriteLine("    " + item.Id);
  Console.WriteLine("  Items in the context:");
  foreach (var item in context.SchoolclassCodes.Local)
    Console.WriteLine("    " + item.Id);
}
```

Most of the code is the same as in Experiment 1; please pay attention to the  lines beginning with `context.Entry(pupil)...`. The output:

```
Books partial query load
  IsLoaded = False
  Items in the pupil:
    1
  Items in the context:
    1
SchoolclassCodes partial query load
  IsLoaded = False
  Items in the pupil:
  Items in the context:
    1
```

See the difference?

1. `IsLoaded` is now `false` in both cases;
2. the loaded data still go into the context;
3. however, the loaded data do not go into the navigation property in the `SchoolclassCodes` case, while it do in the `Books` case.

The difference is caused by the types of relationship: `Books` is one-to-many, while `SchoolclassCodes` is many-to-many. Entity Framework treats those two types differently.

#### Experiment 3: Full Load with Query

So what if we use `Query` without a `Where`? Let's see:

```
using (var context = new SchoolEntities()) {
  Console.WriteLine("Books full query load");
  var pupil = context.Pupils.First();
  context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.Books).Query().Load();
  // output statements omitted...
}
using (var context = new SchoolEntities()) {
  Console.WriteLine("SchoolclassCodes full query load");
  var pupil = context.Pupils.First();
  context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Query().Load();
  // output statements omitted...
}
```

The output:

```
Books full query load
  IsLoaded = False
  Items in the pupil:
    1
    2
  Items in the context:
    1
    2
SchoolclassCodes full query load
  IsLoaded = False
  Items in the pupil:
  Items in the context:
    1
    2
    3
```

Even though we load all the related data, `IsLoaded` is still false, and the loaded data still do not go into `SchoolclassCodes`. Apparently `Load()` is not the same as `Query().Load()`.

#### Source Code of the Query Method

So what's happening under the hood? The source code of EF6 can be found on [CodePlex](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest). The following `Query` call:

```
context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.Books).Query()
```

can be traced to the following code fragment, which I have edited for clarity:

```
string sourceQuery = GenerateQueryText();
var query = new ObjectQuery<TEntity>(sourceQuery, _context, mergeOption);
AddQueryParameters(query);
return query;
```

Here `TEntity` is `Book`, `_context` is the `ObjectContext` behind our `DbContext`, and `sourceQuery` is the following Entity SQL statement:

```
SELECT VALUE [TargetEntity]
FROM (SELECT VALUE x
      FROM [SchoolEntities].[Pupil_Books] AS x
      WHERE Key(x.[Pupil_Books_Source]) = ROW(@EntityKeyValue1 AS EntityKeyValue1)) AS [AssociationEntry]
INNER JOIN [SchoolEntities].[Books] AS [TargetEntity]
  ON Key([AssociationEntry].[Pupil_Books_Target]) = Key(Ref([TargetEntity]))
```

After `AddQueryParameters` the parameter `@EntityKeyValue1` is bound to the value `1`, which is the `Id` of the `pupil`. So the above query is basically the same as:

```
context.Books.Where(s => s.Pupil.Id == pupil.Id)
```

That is, the `Query` method just constructs a query that retrieves `Books` with `Pupil.Id` matching `Id` of the given pupil. It has nothing to do with loading data into `pupil.Books`. This also holds in the case of `pupil.SchoolclassCodes`.

#### Source Code of the Collection's Load Method

Next we check the following method call:

```
context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.Book).Load()
```

This `Load` call leads to the following (edited again for clarity):

```
var sourceQuery = CreateSourceQuery<TEntity>(mergeOption, out hasResults);
IEnumerable<TEntity> refreshedValues;
refreshedValues = sourceQuery.Execute(sourceQuery.MergeOption);
Merge(refreshedValues, mergeOption, true /*setIsLoaded*/);
```

As you can see, it constructs a query, which is exactly the same query we've seen above, then it executes the query and receives the data in `refreshedValues`, and finally it merges the data into the navigation property, i.e. `pupil.Books`.

#### Source Code of the Load Method Following Query

What if we do `Load` after `Query`?

```
context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.Book).Query().Load()
```

This `Load` is defined as an extension method in the `QueryableExtensions` class, and it's quite straightforward:

```
public static void Load(this IQueryable source)
{
    Check.NotNull(source, "source");

    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        var asDisposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
        if (asDisposable != null)
        {
            asDisposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, this time the full source code is shown; I didn't edit anything. And that's right, it is effectively an empty `foreach`, looping through all the loaded items and do absolutely nothing with them. Except something has been done: those items are added into the context, and if the relationship is one-to-many, relationship fix-up kicks in and fixes the associations up. This is part of the enumerator's job.

#### One More Experiment: Side Load

In the above we see that the collection's `Query` method simply constructs an ordinary query (an IQueryable). There are, of course, more than one way to construct such a query. We don't have to begin with `context.Entry(...).Collection(...)`. We can begin right from the top:

```
using (var context = new SchoolEntities()) {
  Console.WriteLine("Books side load");
  var pupil = context.Pupils.First();
  context.Books.Where(s => s.Pupil.Id == pupil.Id).Load();
  // output statements omitted...
}
using (var context = new SchoolEntities()) {
  Console.WriteLine("SchoolclassCodes side load");
  var pupil = context.Pupils.First();
  context.SchoolclassCodes.Where(s => s.Pupils.Select(t => t.Id).Contains(pupil.Id)).Load();
  // output statements omitted...
}
```

The output:

```
Books side load
  IsLoaded = False
  Items in the pupil:
    1
    2
  Items in the context:
    1
    2
SchoolclassCodes side load
  IsLoaded = False
  Items in the pupil:
  Items in the context:
    1
    2
    3
```

Exactly the same as in Experiment 3.

## Update 2

To delete part of the associations in a many-to-many relationship, the officially recommended way is to `Load` all the related objects first and then remove the associations. For example:

```
context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Load();
var code = pupil.SchoolclassCodes.Where(...).First();
pupil.SchoolclassCodes.Remove(code);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This might, of course, load unneeded related objects from the database. If that's undesirable, we can drop down to ObjectContext and use ObjectStateManager:

```
var code = context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Query().Where(...).First();
var objectStateManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
objectStateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(pupil, code, p => p.SchoolclassCodes, EntityState.Deleted);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This way only the relevant related object is loaded. In fact, if we already know the primary key of the related object, even that one can be eliminated:

```
var code = new SchoolclassCode { Id = 1 };
context.SchoolclassCodes.Attach(code);
var objectStateManager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
objectStateManager.ChangeRelationshipState(pupil, code, p => p.SchoolclassCodes, EntityState.Deleted);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Note, however, that [EF7 will remove ObjectContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/27/ef7-v1-or-v7.aspx), so the above code will have to be modified if we want to migrate to EF7 in the future.

Comment: Please remove the paragraph about the compiler does not compile. That was not my problem. Why I say the top query does not work it means there is no SchoolclassCode result.

Comment: I do not agree at all with your statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx  QUOTE:"The Query method provides access to the underlying query that the Entity Framework will use when loading related entities. You can then use LINQ to apply filters to the query before executing it with a call to a LINQ extension method such as ToList, Load, etc. The Query method can be used with both reference and collection navigation properties but is most useful for collections where it can be used to load only part of the collection." Thats the same N:M relation and the same query!

Comment: See in the above attached link "Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities"

Comment: Thanks now its correct and I understood. As I have entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Query().Where(...) but the schoolcalssCode is not returned inside the pupil.SchoolclassCodes I also can not do pupil.Schoolclasscodes.Rremove(context..Schoolclasscodes.Local.First()) because as we found out the schoolclassCode is NOT inside the parent entity known as pupil. Thus I have to load all schoolclasscodes for this one pupil and filter then via Linq to Objects. Or do you know a better approach?

Comment: No need to load all of them. You can still use `Query` and `Where`, just don't use `Load`, like this: `var codes = context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Query().Where(...); context.SchoolclassCodes.RemoveRange(codes); context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: No No... I can not remove the schoolclassCode from the context.SchoolclassCodes because that would DELETE the schoolclassCode finally. What I do/did via pupil.Schoolclasscodes.Remove is just removing the relation between those two entities, you understand?

Comment: Well, in that case, I'm afraid you'll have to load the whole collection and then remove: `context.Entry(pupil).Collection(p => p.SchoolclassCodes).Load(); pupil.SchoolclassCodes.Remove(...); context.SaveChanges();` At least, this is the "official" way I've seen. I'll try to find a better solution, and will let you know if I find one.

Comment: Thanks for the last update. I will not use it as yes I plan to migrate to EF7 end of year when its usable... Your cool findings prove once more again that its good that EF7 changes a lot under the hood and makes common tasks a breath hopefully. Thanks again :-)